# Can't find the right regex for pattern

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to get a regex that matches the following pattern:

```
_Something6
```

When everything has to start with an underscore and has to be followed by an uppercase letter, then any letter or number, but not an underscore or any special characters anymore.

I have this, but as you may see, I'm not a regex genius

```
^/_[A-Z][a-z+][0-9]
```

I'd appreciate any help with this.

Comment: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html A regex tutorial or two might be a good idea; it's valuable. Your `+` is in the wrong place, and you have a seemingly-random `/` near the beginning there.

Comment: Why did you try to use the `/`. Have you seen somehow a javascript example, or you wanted to escape a character (that would be `\\`)?

Comment: I was reading some tutorials and I thinked that any special character needed an / before it.

Comment: The underscore isn't actually a special character, and doesn't need to be escaped. Also, you've got the wrong slash. E.g., to match the literal character `[`, you'd need the regex: `\[`.

Comment: show me the link to that tutorial (it must have been \ not /). Underscore it not a special character anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try : `^_[A-Z][a-z0-9]+` . That was start off by :

```
^_ : match the beginning of the string
[A-Z] : followed by an uppercase letter
[a-z0-9]+ : followed by any lowercase letters or numerics
```

Comment: IMO `[a-z0-9]` would be the canonical representation of a character range.

Comment: The | in your second character class is unnecessary, and I actually believe that it matches a literal | in that context, so e.g. "_Some|thing6" would be matched by this regex. Also, since you don't have an end anchor ($), something like this would also match: "_So_Something6".

Answer (score 3):

This should be it: ^_[A-Z][a-z]+[0-9]

As the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) say:

- `^` beginning of line
- `_` underscore
- `[A-Z]` any capital letter form A to Z (only one)
- `[a-z]+` any small letter form a to z (at least once)
- `[0-9]` a digit

and to make sure it ends there (with the digit) suffix it with a `$`:

```
^_[A-Z][a-z]+[0-9]$
```

Comment: I have just one problem with that, and it's that this match:

    _something5
It ignores the uppercase letter.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: OP specifically states "then any letter or number".

Comment: @UrielHernández That's not possible; it cannot match a lower-case letter as the second character.

Comment: `^_[A-Z]?[a-z]+[0-9]` the `?` should make the capital letter optional. But would still allow it only as the first character after the _

Comment: @Raystorm But OP states it's not optional.

Comment: @Gabriel The OP says "then any letter or number", so I think uppercase letters and numbers should be allowed in the middle, and I don't think it needs to end with a number.

Comment: @DaveNewton but the first comment on this answer is OP saying it didn't match _something6 even though it matched _Something6

Comment: I'm sorry if my question is not clear enough, It's because of my english. It works great, I was doing something bad and that was the reason for what I said before.

Comment: how about `_\w+\d` or `_(\w\d)+` ? those would both match any letter or number after the _ the different being if letters the numbers can only be *after* the letters or not.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
^_[A-Z][\w&&[^_]]+$
```

[image: Regex UI]

Comment: `[\w&&[^_]]` is shorter to write than `[a-zA-Z0-9]` (8 vs 9 chars). But you should think of complexity that implies this kind of syntaxe. however I notice you have read the OP wish

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
^_[A-Z][A-Za-z\d]+$
```

The `[A-Za-z]` could also be `[A-Z]|[a-z]` if that makes more sense to you. The `\d` is a pseudonym for `[0-9]` - again, use whichever is more clear for you.

Your example is somewhat unclear, so a couple of examples:

```
String a = "_Som3th1ng6";    // This matches.
String b = "_Some_thing";    // This DOES NOT match.
```

If you want to match only strings that END with numbers, something like this would work:

```
^_[A-Z][A-Za-z]+\d+$
```

The `^` and `$` are matching the start and end of the string, so for example:

```
String a = "_Something6";     // This matches.
String b = " _Something6 ";   // This DOES NOT match.
```

If this isn't what you want, omit those two characters.